# How do you plot a single row of values from csv?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a CSV file with the stocks of the BEL-20 and I need to write a function that will give me the graph of the values of a single stock. That single stock is defined by the Ticker word, for example Ticker = TNET is Telenet, so I need to make a graph with the stocks from Telenet. The values are all in the CSV file i got. The x and y axis where given by my teacher.
Thanks in advance.

```py
def graph(Ticker):
    aandeel = pd.read_csv("beurskoersen.csv", sep=";", encoding='latin-1')
    xAs = aandeel.columns[2:26]
    yAs = aandeel.iloc[0,2:26]
    plt.plot(xAs, yAs)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the data to a dataframe, you can filter it with the needed value.

```
aandeel = pd.read_csv("beurskoersen.csv", sep=";", encoding='latin-1')
aandeel_filtered = aandeel[aandeel['Ticker'] == Ticker]
```